# Find next element out of parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, nextsibling

I've the following DOM structure:

```
<label>
  <span class="tt">
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello1</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello2</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello3</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello4</a>
  </span>
  <a href="#" class="editable">Hello5</a>
</label>
```

When I click on the anchor `Hello3`, I need to get `Hello4` and its working absolutely fine. But If I click on the link `Hello4`, I need to get `Hello5` which I'm not getting correctly.

I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','.editable',function(){
  console.log($(this).nextAll('.editable').first());
});
```

What I actually want is to get the next element having class of `editable` in the label tag when I click on an anchor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use nextAll() as it is based on sibling elements, in your case all the `editable` elements are not siblings.

You can use a index based lookup to find the next element like

```js
$(document).on('click', '.editable', function() {
  var $all = $('.editable');
  snippet.log($all.eq($all.index(this) + 1).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<label>
  <span class="tt">
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello1</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello2</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello3</a>
    <a href="#" class="editable">Hello4</a>
  </span>
  <a href="#" class="editable">Hello5</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the siblings function that returns all siblings of a given element in addition with class selector that select elements of a specific class.
Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.editable',function(){
  console.log($('.tt').siblings('.editable').first());
});
```